# Daily magnitude of Betelgeuse

Tags: betelgeuse

I tried searching on the internet and could not find anything, so does anyone know if there's a website which tracks and shows Betelgeuse's magnitude daily?  I just went out today and saw that it's now about the same brightness as Bellatrix.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you might also find this article interesting as it chimes with your observation: https://astronomynow.com/2020/02/14/esos-very-large-telescope-shows-dramatic-dimming-of-betelgeuse/

Comment: The website from the [American Association of Variable Star Observers](https://www.aavso.org/star-month-february-2020-alpha-ori) has info about the magnitude variations of Betelgeuse in its "Star of the Month" article.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The American Association of Variable Star Observers tracks observations of a number of variable stars, [including Betelgeuse](https://www.aavso.org/apps/webobs/results/?star=Betelgeuse). There are typically many such observations each day, primarily at visible wavelengths. It's quite easy to [generate a light curve](https://www.aavso.org/LCGv2/) in the band(s) and date range of your choice.

I'm also aware of [a Twitter bot](https://twitter.com/betelbot) that tweets light curves from AAVSO data several times a day, including long-term projections, but I assume you'd be more interested in looking at the individual measurements yourself.

Comment: There's quite a bit of variation in the measurements, though, e.g. from 0.423 to 3.3151. Is this expected?

Comment: @EricDuminil One of those is in the R band and one of those is in the B band, so it's not surprising. Different wavelength filters will give different magnitudes for a particular object.